# Mocking Hangfire RecurringJob Dependency in .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire

Consider the following controller:

```
public class SubmissionController : Controller
{ 
    public SubmissionController()
    { }

    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => InitiateSubmission(), Cron.Minutely);

        return Ok("Periodic submission triggered");
    }
}
```

Does Hangfire offer an abstraction inject a dependency for RecurringJob class? I have done some research and the only available abstraction is `IBackgroundJobClient`, which does not have the option to schedule a recurring job.

I need to verify that the job has been added in a unit test.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/RecurringJob.cs) of `RecurringJob` class, you will see that its static methods result in call to `RecurringJobManager` class:

```
public static class RecurringJob
{
    private static readonly Lazy<RecurringJobManager> Instance = new Lazy<RecurringJobManager>(
        () => new RecurringJobManager());

    //  ...

    public static void AddOrUpdate(
        Expression<Action> methodCall,
        string cronExpression,
        TimeZoneInfo timeZone = null,
        string queue = EnqueuedState.DefaultQueue)
    {
        var job = Job.FromExpression(methodCall);
        var id = GetRecurringJobId(job);

        Instance.Value.AddOrUpdate(id, job, cronExpression, timeZone ?? TimeZoneInfo.Utc, queue);
    }

    //  ...
}
```

`RecurringJobManager` implements `IRecurringJobManager` interface which you could use for dependency injection and mock in UT.

However `RecurringJob` has internal logic for getting a job from lambda and building a job id:

```
var job = Job.FromExpression(methodCall);
var id = GetRecurringJobId(job);
```

`Job.FromExpression()` is a public method that you can safely use. However `GetRecurringJobId` is a private method defined as following:

```
private static string GetRecurringJobId(Job job)
{
    return $"{job.Type.ToGenericTypeString()}.{job.Method.Name}";
}
```

`GetRecurringJobId` basically returns name of job method in form of `SubmissionController.InitiateSubmission`. It's based on internal class `TypeExtensions` with extension methods for `Type`. You can't use this class directly since it is internal, so you should duplicate that logic.

If you follow this approach your final solution would be:

**TypeExtensions** (copied from [Hangfire sources](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Common/TypeExtensions.cs)):

```
static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static string ToGenericTypeString(this Type type)
    {
        if (!type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType)
        {
            return type.GetFullNameWithoutNamespace()
                .ReplacePlusWithDotInNestedTypeName();
        }

        return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            .GetFullNameWithoutNamespace()
            .ReplacePlusWithDotInNestedTypeName()
            .ReplaceGenericParametersInGenericTypeName(type);
    }

    private static string GetFullNameWithoutNamespace(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericParameter)
        {
            return type.Name;
        }

        const int dotLength = 1;
        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace)
            ? type.FullName.Substring(type.Namespace.Length + dotLength)
            : type.FullName;
    }

    private static string ReplacePlusWithDotInNestedTypeName(this string typeName)
    {
        return typeName.Replace('+', '.');
    }

    private static string ReplaceGenericParametersInGenericTypeName(this string typeName, Type type)
    {
        var genericArguments = type.GetTypeInfo().GetAllGenericArguments();

        const string regexForGenericArguments = @"`[1-9]\d*";

        var rgx = new Regex(regexForGenericArguments);

        typeName = rgx.Replace(typeName, match =>
        {
            var currentGenericArgumentNumbers = int.Parse(match.Value.Substring(1));
            var currentArguments = string.Join(",", genericArguments.Take(currentGenericArgumentNumbers).Select(ToGenericTypeString));
            genericArguments = genericArguments.Skip(currentGenericArgumentNumbers).ToArray();
            return string.Concat("<", currentArguments, ">");
        });

        return typeName;
    }

    public static Type[] GetAllGenericArguments(this TypeInfo type)
    {
        return type.GenericTypeArguments.Length > 0 ? type.GenericTypeArguments : type.GenericTypeParameters;
    }
}
```

**RecurringJobManagerExtensions:**

```
public static class RecurringJobManagerExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate(this IRecurringJobManager manager, Expression<Action> methodCall, Func<string> cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZone = null, string queue = EnqueuedState.DefaultQueue)
    {
        var job = Job.FromExpression(methodCall);
        var id = $"{job.Type.ToGenericTypeString()}.{job.Method.Name}";

        manager.AddOrUpdate(id, job, cronExpression(), timeZone ?? TimeZoneInfo.Utc, queue);
    }
}
```

**Controller with injected `IRecurringJobManager`:**

```
public class SubmissionController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager;

    public SubmissionController(IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager)
    {
        this.recurringJobManager = recurringJobManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(() => InitiateSubmission(), Cron.Minutely);

        return Ok("Periodic submission triggered");
    }

    public void InitiateSubmission()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Well, this approach will work, but I'm not a fan of it. It's based on some internal Hangfire stuff that could be changed in the future.

That's why I suggest to use another approach. You could add new facade interface (e.g. `IRecurringJobFacade`) which will mimic methods from `RecurringJob` that you are going to use. Implementation of this interface will just call corresponding `RecurringJob` methods. Then you inject this `IRecurringJobFacade` into the controller and could easily mock it in UT. Here is a sample:

**IRecurringJobFacade:**

```
public interface IRecurringJobFacade
{
    void AddOrUpdate(Expression<Action> methodCall, Func<string> cronExpression);

    //  Mimic other methods from RecurringJob that you are going to use.
    // ...
}
```

**RecurringJobFacade:**

```
public class RecurringJobFacade : IRecurringJobFacade
{
    public void AddOrUpdate(Expression<Action> methodCall, Func<string> cronExpression)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(methodCall, cronExpression);
    }
}
```

**Controller with injected `IRecurringJobFacade`:**

```
public class SubmissionController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRecurringJobFacade recurringJobFacade;

    public SubmissionController(IRecurringJobFacade recurringJobFacade)
    {
        this.recurringJobFacade = recurringJobFacade;
    }

    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        recurringJobFacade.AddOrUpdate(() => InitiateSubmission(), Cron.Minutely);

        return Ok("Periodic submission triggered");
    }

    public void InitiateSubmission()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you see this approach is much simpler and most importantly it's much more reliable, since it does not dig into Hangfire internals and just calls `RecurringJob` methods as usual.

Such facade interface is often used when code could not be mocked directly (static methods or classes not based on interfaces). Some other examples that I have used in my practice: mock of `System.IO.File`, `DateTime.Now`, `System.Timers.Timer`, etc.

Comment: Your answer helped me to inject IRecurringJobFacade into my component (a service instead of a controller btw) and mock RecurringJob functionality.
One addition though: in my case the methodCall param of the .AddOrUpdate method contains param(s) itself:

recurringJobFacade.AddOrUpdate(activity.Id.ToString(), () => RunTask(file, activity), cron);

As a result I got the following error:
"Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

Comment: The solution is to use the RecurringJobManager in the implementation of the facade interface:
    public class RecurringJobFacade : IRecurringJobFacade
    {
        public void AddOrUpdate(string recurringJobId, Expression<Action> methodCall, string cronExpression)
        {
            RecurringJobManager manager = new RecurringJobManager();
            manager.AddOrUpdate(recurringJobId, methodCall, cronExpression);
        } 
}  
Thus arguments/parameters can be passed. Apologies for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case with: `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists`. I try this (I see the original code in github and setup my mock's):

```
    private void SetupHangfire()
    {
        Mock<JobStorage> _jobStorageMock = new Mock<JobStorage>();
        Mock<IStorageConnection> _storageConnectionMock = new Mock<IStorageConnection>();
        Mock<IWriteOnlyTransaction> _transactionConnectionMock = new Mock<IWriteOnlyTransaction>();

        JobStorage.Current = _jobStorageMock.Object;

        _jobStorageMock
            .Setup(y => y.GetConnection())
            .Returns(_storageConnectionMock.Object);

        _storageConnectionMock
            .Setup(y => y.AcquireDistributedLock(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()))
            .Returns(_transactionConnectionMock.Object);

        _storageConnectionMock
            .Setup(y => y.CreateWriteTransaction())
            .Returns(_transactionConnectionMock.Object);

        _transactionConnectionMock
            .Setup(y => y.RemoveHash(It.IsAny<string>()));

        _transactionConnectionMock
            .Setup(y => y.RemoveFromSet(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));

        _transactionConnectionMock
            .Setup(y => y.Commit());
    }
```